# How to fix 'no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘Matrix<double, 2, 3>’ and ‘Matrix<double, 3, 2>’)' with templates

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm trying to implement a template based Matrix class in C++17. The class should override operator*() to allow formulations such as

```
Matrix<double, 2, 3> a = {{{3,2,1},{1,0,2}}};
Matrix<double, 3, 2> b = {{{1,2},{0,1},{4,0}}};
Matrix c = a * b;
```

but this is causing a compiler error.

```
no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘Matrix<double, 2, 3>’ and ‘Matrix<double, 3, 2>’)
   43 |     Matrix c = a * b;
      |                ~ ^ ~
      |                |   |
      |                |   Matrix<[...],3,2>
      |                Matrix<[...],2,3>
```

I know in principle Matrix a and b are completely different types but somehow I think it should be possible because both, 2nd and 3rd, template arguments are of type size_t.

```
template <typename T, size_t nbRows, size_t nbColumns>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T>> &&vector) {
        assert(vector.size() == nbRows);
        assert(vector.front().size() == nbColumns);

        auto matrixIter = matrix.begin();
        for(auto && row : vector) {
            std::copy_n(std::make_move_iterator(row.begin()), nbColumns, matrixIter);
            std::advance(matrixIter, nbColumns);
        }
    }

    friend inline Matrix operator*(Matrix lhs, const Matrix &rhs) {
        // Compute the product of lhs and rhs
        return lhs;
    }

private:
    std::array<T, nbRows * nbColumns> matrix;
};
```

Comment: When you write `friend inline Matrix operator*(Matrix lhs, const Matrix &rhs)`, the compiler sees this as exactly the same as if you wrote `friend inline Matrix<T, nbRows, nbColumns> operator*(Matrix<T, nbRows, nbColumns> lhs, const Matrix<T, nbRows, nbColumns> &rhs)`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `operator*` applies to `Matrix<A, B>` and `Matrix<A, B>` (same types) but not `Matrix<A, B>` and `Matrix<B, A>` (different types). Instead of defining the operator within the class template, do it as a free function outside of the class template like so:

```
template<typename T, size_t LhsRows, size_t LhsColumns, size_t RhsRows, size_t RhsColumns>
auto operator*(const Matrix<T, LhsRows, LhsColumns>& lhs, const Matrix<T, RhsRows, RhsColumns>& rhs)
{
    static_assert(LhsColumns == RhsRows, "unrelated matrix sizes");

    // ...
}
```

This way you can apply the operator to two different instantiations of the `Matrix` class template.

Comment: Should you not restrict it to cases were LhsRows == RhsColumns so that matrix with unrelated sizes can't be multiplied ? You could probably do it by reusing the type in the template definition

Comment: @Jeffrey `static_assert` in the body is a good way to do this. This also allows for a message describing the problem, which is generally preferable to template error spew.

Comment: @vasama, can you please edit the static_assert in the answer? It makes the answer quite satisfactory.

Comment: @Jeffey @vasama, yes `static_assert` the number rows and columns is necessary. But that wasn't the question. The clarification was only necessary for the operators header.

Answer (score 2):

Make the `operator*` function a template, that takes other sets of "rows" and "columns":

```
template<size_t rows1, size_t cols1, size_t rows2, size_t cols2>
friend inline Matrix operator*(Matrix<T, rows1, cols1> lhs, const Matrix<T, rows2, cols2> &rhs) {
    // Compute the product of lhs and rhs
    return lhs;
}
```

Or if you only want to handle the reverse (switching "rows" and "columns") then use that for the classes in the argument list:

```
friend inline Matrix operator*(Matrix<T, nbRows, nbColumns> lhs, const Matrix<T, nbColumns, nbRows> &rhs) {
    // Compute the product of lhs and rhs
    return lhs;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The two arguments for your operator have different types. You need to introduce a template argument for the number of columns in the second argument and the number of columns in the resulting type. You can then replace `Matrix` with the proper type for each use :

```
template<size_t nbOther>
friend inline Matrix<T, nbRows, nbOther> operator*(
    const Matrix<T, nbRows, nbColumns> & lhs,
    const Matrix<T, nbColumns, nbOther> &rhs)
{
    // Do math
}
```

Since matrix multiplication requires that the inner dimension are the same, you only need 1 additional template argument. Any other information you need is already provided by the `class` template arguments.

As a final note, `operator*` should not return `lhs`. Normally the `operator*=` variant of the operator would return a reference to `lhs` but you won't be able to implement it here since the operation would need to change the type of `lhs` which is not possible in c++. The return value will be a distinct matrix of type `Matrix<T, nbRows, nbOther>` which generally wont be the same type as either of the parameters.

Comment: That. Reusing nbColumns twice is the way to maintain matrix compatibility

Answer (score 0):

As you said a & b have different types `Matrix<double, 2, 3> and Matrix<double, 3, 2>`

so your operator overload will become something like this

```
friend inline Matrix<double, 2, 3> operator*(Matrix<double, 2, 3> lhs, const Matrix<double, 2, 3> &rhs) {
    // Compute the product of lhs and rhs
    return lhs;
}
```

that is the reason of why the compiler cannot find the proper operator overload for your class, so in order to solve this you should add an overload where rhs columns are equal to lhs rows but rhs has a different rows count

```
template<size_t nbColsR>
friend inline Matrix<T, nbRows, nbColsR> operator*(Matrix lhs, const Matrix<T, nbColumns, nbColsR> &rhs) {
        // Compute the product of lhs and rhs
        return lhs;
}
```